# Javascript Submit Form not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can anyone see why this form is not submitting ? I have an asp page with a form, the button is outside the form so I need it to submit using javascript. The alert box does appear but the form will not submit.

```
<script>
    function validatelink255(){
        var promptbox = (confirm('Update Despatch Confirmations?')) ;
        if (promptbox == true){
            document.Despatchform.submit();

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="purchaseorderfile_detaildespatchupdate.asp?orderno=<%=orderno%>&suppliername=<%=address1%>" method="post" name="Despatchform" id="Despatchform">
    <input name="<%=lineno%>checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" 
        <%if despatchconfirmed = "yes" then%>
        checked="checked" 
        <%end if%>
    />
</form>

<input type="submit" name="button33" id="button33" value="Save Despatch Confirmations" onClick="return validatelink255(this);"/>
```

I have just tried changing the javascript in the head section to the code below. I get the hello alert but not hello2.

```
<script>
    function validatelink255(){
        var promptbox = (confirm('Update Despatch Confirmations?')) ;
        if (promptbox == true){
            alert("hello");
            document.forms['Despatchform'].submit();
            alert("hello2");
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use console.log("") and see whether it goes inside the if loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i see is that, you are not passing the form for submit,

try this

```
<script>
function validatelink255(form){
var promptbox = (confirm('Update Despatch Confirmations?')) ;
if (promptbox == true){
form.submit();}
else{
return false;}
}
</script>


  <form action="purchaseorderfile_detaildespatchupdate.asp?orderno=<%=orderno%>&suppliername=<%=address1%>" method="post" name="Despatchform" id="Despatchform">

 <input name="<%=lineno%>checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" 
 <%if despatchconfirmed = "yes" then%>
 checked="checked" 
 <%end if%>
 />
 </form>


 <input type="submit" name="button33" id="button33" value="Save Despatch Confirmations" onClick="return validatelink255(Despatchform);"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input tag multiline code might be problem.

```html
<input name="<%=lineno%>checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" <%if despatchconfirmed = "yes" then%> checked="checked" <%end if%>
```